# JMeter: Hot to avoid interval among TCP sampler requests

Tags: tcp, jmeter

There is a interval(about 2 seconds) between TCP requests "login-bam" and "heatbeat" after "login-bam" sended, can anyone  tell me how to avoid this interval that will be really appreciate.

I checked NoDelay box , but no use.

Here is the JMeter Plan script(.jmx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.5">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">true</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <TCPSampler guiclass="TCPSamplerGui" testclass="TCPSampler" testname="login-bam" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.classname">BinaryTCPClientImpl</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.server">10.3.0.132</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.reUseConnection">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.port">60101</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.nodelay">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.timeout">2000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.ctimeout">2000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.request">630000000100003133366132396537316335373435653538313366666465666138633264633739023401002220807b227479706522203a202242414d222c22696422203a202231222c2276657222203a2022312e302e30222c22687274223a2234227d</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.closeConnection">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.soLinger">0</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ConfigTestElement.username"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ConfigTestElement.password"></stringProp>
        </TCPSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <TCPSampler guiclass="TCPSamplerGui" testclass="TCPSampler" testname="heatbeat" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.classname">BinaryTCPClientImpl</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.server">10.3.0.132</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.reUseConnection">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.port">60101</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.nodelay">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.timeout">10000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.ctimeout">10000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.request">2f0000000100006332373265613362646163373435626239343039333030313537313362393165023300002220477d</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="TCPSampler.closeConnection">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="TCPSampler.soLinger">0</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ConfigTestElement.username"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ConfigTestElement.password"></stringProp>
        </TCPSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter waits for response from the previous request before sending the next request. So your `heartbeat` will be executed only after `login-bam` request is finished.

If you want them to be executed at the same time there are following options:

1. Put them under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter), it runs its children at the same time in parallel.
3. Increase the number of threads to 2 and add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer), this way both requests will be executed at the same moment, when the longest of them will finish execution both will be kicked off again, etc.